# Is there a way to adjust the annotations in a matplot scatterplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, annotations

Currently I struggle to move the annotations in a scatterplot for better readability.
This is my code:

```
    for line in range(0, data_wald_nan.shape[0]):
        fig.text(data_wald_nan.Wald_Schools_Per_Million.iloc[line] + 0.01, data_wald_nan.vaxx_rate.iloc[line],
                data_wald_nan.country.iloc[line], horizontalalignment='left',
                size='medium', color='black', weight='semibold')
```

I tried using adjust text but this just draws way too much red arrows:

```
    for x,y,s in zip(data_wald_nan[independend_variable], data_wald_nan["vaxx_rate"], data_wald_nan["country"]):
        texts.append(plt.text(x, y, s))
        adjust_text(texts, only_move={'points': 'y', 'texts': 'y'}, 
    arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->", color='r', lw=0.5))
    plt.show()
```

This is the Output of Code 1:
[image]

And this the Output of Code 2:
[image]

EDIT: minimalistic code:

```
import scipy.stats
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
from adjustText import adjust_text

def scatter(independend_variable):
    data = pd.read_csv("RQ1_final.csv")

    data_wald_nan = pd.read_csv("RQ1_final.csv")
    colors = np.arange((len(data_wald_nan["vaxx_rate"])))
    print(data_wald_nan)
    r = [scipy.stats.pearsonr(x=data_wald_nan["vaxx_rate"], y=data_wald_nan[independend_variable])]
    print()
    y = data_wald_nan["vaxx_rate"]
    x = data_wald_nan[independend_variable]
    fig = sns.scatterplot(data=data_wald_nan, y="vaxx_rate", x=independend_variable, c = colors)
    fig.set_title( "Gross domestic product and \n vaccination rate "
                                             "in countries \n (correlation-coefficient: " + str(r) +
                 ")", weight="bold")
    fig.set_ylabel("Vaccination Rate in %")
    fig.set_xlabel("Gross domestic product")

    for line in range(0, data_wald_nan.shape[0]):
        fig.text(data_wald_nan.GDP.iloc[line] + 0.01, data_wald_nan.vaxx_rate.iloc[line],
                data_wald_nan.country.iloc[line], horizontalalignment='left',
                size='medium', color='black', weight='semibold')
        adjust_text(fig.texts,only_move={'points': 'y', 'texts': 'y'}, arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->", color='r', lw=0.5))
    fig.set_ylim(ymin=0, ymax=100)
    fig.set_xlim(xmin=5000,xmax=100000)
    plt.grid(visible=True, color="grey", linestyle="-", linewidth=0.5, alpha=0.2)
    plt.show()
scatter("GDP")
```

Comment: The distribution of many text annotations is often non-trivial and not supported natively by most libraries. You might be interested in [`adjustText`](https://github.com/Phlya/adjustText)

Comment: @Mr.T the second code shows me using AdjustText, but I cant get it to work :/

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete, and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). If you don't provide stand-alone code that replicates your problem, it is difficult to suggest solutions. Imports and sample inputs are part of a minimal example.

Comment: @Mr.T okay I edited the post! Thanks!

Comment: As we do not have your input data, we cannot reproduce your problem. This is what is meant by minimal, complete, and reproducible example - the smallest entity that allows as a stand-alone to reproduce the problem. We only know what you post here but you have to restrict it to the bare minimum because nobody wants to debug 500 lines of uncommented code for you.